# adding a new property to existing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to add another property to existing object returning from `findOne()` promise in mongoose.
In the response I get the object without the property `convertName`

```
app.get('/getItem', (req, res) => {

var itemID = req.query.itemID;

Item.findOne({_id: itemID}).then(item => {

    item.convertName = 'cm';
    res.send(item);

  }).catch( err => {
    res.status(401).send();
  });
})
```

I know that the way to add another property to an existing object is similar to this, just specify the property name and set a value to it, so I don't know why it is not working in this case.

Hope you can explain and help me why its not working.

Comment: What happens when you add `lean()` into the chain? Like `Item.findOne({_id: itemID}).lean().then(...)`

Comment: its working! what does lean() do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated with Mongoose: by default `MongooseDocument` is returned by query, and the property that you try to add to such a document is not reflected on its serialized value (the one that is sent in the response).

One possible way around this is using `lean()` method to enable lean option. Quoting [the doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

> Documents returned from queries with the `lean` option enabled are plain
>   javascript objects, not `MongooseDocuments`. They have no save method,
>   getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.